# How to use Google Translate API in .net core website?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, google-translate, google-translation-api

How can I use Google Translate api in my .NET core application? I had tried basic html and text translation both are working fine. Now I want to convert my whole website into multi language. How can I do that. For reference I am using [this link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text)

Comment: were you able to get any help?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could code something like this to translate a sentence:

```
var sentence = "This is some html text to <strong>translate</strong>!";
// Target language is french
string targetLanguage = "fr";
// Source language is automatically detected
string sourceLanguage = null; 
// We create the TranslationClient
var client = Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationClient.Create();
// We translate
var response = client.TranslateHtml(sentence, targetLanguage, sourceLanguage);
// Output
Console.WriteLine(response.TranslatedText);
// C&#39;est un texte html à <strong>traduire</strong> !
```

[Code source](https://www.meziantou.net/using-the-google-translate-api-in-dotnet-or-dotnet-core.htm)

[Official documentation on how to get started using the Google Translate API in .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started)

[.NET reference documentation for the Cloud Translation API.](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Translate.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Translate.v3.html)

Comment: Any sample code or blogs contains step by step implementation?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example I just found.

Answer (score 1):

Google translation api implementation with .Net core 6 api
Github link
https://github.com/Ubaidurrehman10/Google-api-translator
for this repo you just need to set the “GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS” to the file path of the Service account key JSON file you have downloaded from google [Once you clone the application, set the environment variable with the key mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGLp.png).

Comment: https://www.blogofpi.com/using-google-translation-api-with-dotnet-core/